# Should we tag with all terms in a tree?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've noticed a couple of questions that have all of the tags:

- oracle
- oracle-11g
- oracle-11g-r2

Ideally, the tagging would support hierarchies, and know that 'oracle' is a broader term of 'oracle-11g-r2', so we didn't have to put on the redundant tags, but I don't think it currently does.

So, just as a best-practice type thing : should we be tagging at this level of specificity?  If we should, should we also be tagging at the broader level as well?

Answer (score 14):

*My answer has changed.  See the history for the previous version.*

**Rules:**

1. Questions should only have one version tag referring the most specific major version known or applicable.
2. The database product tag should also be present.

**Examples:**

- A question about Oracle 11.1.0.7 should be tagged `Oracle` and `Oracle-11g-r1`.
- A question about Oracle 11g that could apply to either 11.1 or 11.2 should be tagged `Oracle` and `Oracle-11g`.
- A question about Oracle 11g in which it is not known which version is in use should initially get the `Oracle` and `Oracle-11g` tags.  If it is discovered that the question applies only to a more specific version then the appropriate version tag should replace the `Oracle-11g` tag.

*Note:* This is a fleshed out version of jcolebrand's answer.

Comment: I'm not sure we need a separate 11g tag - the releases 10.1,10.2,11.1,11.2 were all major releases and really the naming seems down to marketing. I think I prefer jcolebrand's answer on balance.

Comment: @Jack, so, how would you tag an Oracle 11.1 question?

Comment: I mean keep `oracle`, `oracle-11g-r1` and `oracle-11g-r2` and dispense with (ie blacklist) `oracle-11g` - would that make sense to you?

Comment: @Jack, In theory it sounds good, but in practice it may be difficult to convert `oracle-11g` tags to a more specific `oracle-11g-r1` or `oracle-11g-r2` tag.  Would you assume they are all `r1`?  Going forward it seems difficult enough to get questions that include an `11g` tag let alone getting them to specify `r1` or `r2`.  Having a `r1` tag does sound useful and I see the benefits of removing the `11g` tag when the `11g-r1` or `11g-r2` tag is present, but it seems that blacklisting it may do more harm than good.

Comment: I was thinking about renaming `oracle-11g` to `oracle-11g-r1` and living with the fact that many Qs would than perhaps be incorrectly tagged as you say. Going forward the poster would then be forced to choose `oracle` or a fully version-specific tag. Maybe I'm trying too hard though - do you think we should just live with the fact that `oracle-11g` could mean r1 or r2? The rule then could just be max 2 Oracle tags: `oracle` and optionally something more specific like `oracle-11g` or `oracle-11g-r1`?

Comment: @Jack I understand the temptation.  See my updated answer and create your own (up-vote another) if you don't like it.

Comment: I think I do like it after all :-)

Comment: @Jack, jcolebrand So I guess the thing to do is remove the Oracle-11g/Oracle-11g tags when a more specific version is present.

Comment: no, IIUC I think we are all agreeing that your answers is the way to go, namely keep the tags

Comment: No, keep the base tag, and the version tag, but no intermediate version tags.

Comment: @jcolebrand, exactly.

Comment: I understand - finally :-) 'remove' intermediate tag *from question* not *from site*. Everyone is saying the same thing. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think oracle and oracle-11g-r2 are the only ones needed right now(in the case of this example). We can get tags sorted once we know for sure what tags and synonyms we need. Let's focus on questions for the first week, then we can do tags next week. May sound dumb, but I think it's right.

Comment: Well, now it's next year! I think the tagging hierarchy we should follow is [the one Leigh linked to on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info).

Comment: It's next year and two weeks :D

Answer (score 0):

**No**

As Oracle* matches oracle-11G, there is no need to tag both oracle and 11g unless the question covers *all* oracle databases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm for using most specific tags like oracle-11g-r2, but construct the tags in a way that wildcard tag searches for **oracle*** or **oracle-11*** work fine. Other tags like plsql or sqlplus are perhaps better accompanied with an additional oracle tag