# Automatically add the versionless RDBMS tag when needed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tagging

In [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/should-we-tag-with-all-terms-in-a-tree) meta post there was an apparent agreement on that we should have questions tagged not only with the actual version of the relevant RDBMS (like [postgresql-9.1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.1)) but the versionless tag (here [postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)) as well.  I think we always had questions not conforming to this rule but recently these are so many that apparently noone has the time to clean them up.  (Personally I do it on PostgreSQL related questions and others I edit anyway but there are many more.)

So I would welcome a feature which adds these versionless tags when they are not specified by the OP.  I see there may be some cases when there are already five tags on the question (and quite possibly there are some other problems as well), but still: can we have such a feature?

Comment: There would need to be a mapping table between a tag and it's "versionless" counterpart. Or a table of tags that are product names, so that "versioned", er... versions would be detected automatically (hm, how?). Well, I don't know... And there's this issue of there already being 5 tags, and another potential one of a tag being a synonym...

Comment: I know that was mostly a developer's point of view, but I think it still addresses some aspects of *‘ **can** we...’*.

Comment: Does that get messy for things that have differing version numbering schemes for alternate systems? For example db2 for z/OS has version 10 and version 11. But db2 for LUW (linux, unix, windows) has version 10.1 and version 10.5 (and no, those aren't fix packs either. IBM uses different numbering schemes for db2 for z, db2 for i, and db2 for luw). I can see it both ways. But I'm just wondering what is cleaner. Shouldn't we just encourage people to mention their editions and versions in their questions?

Comment: @ChrisAldrich I'm not very optimistic about people adding the necessary tags.  At the same time I was not aware of the problem you mentioned (and I have to admit I find it _very_ strange) - it will not help implementing this feature.  Probably we can say that 'well, for DB2 we have to make an exception'.

Comment: Sadly, the answer is probably no: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags

Comment: Great suggestion. I often miss SQL Server questions tagged only with the specific version. Sad that it has been declined as Jon notes.