# New Tag for SQL Server Installation

Tags: discussion

I cannot find specific tag ' SQL Server installation' however there is a tag 'Installation'. If we could create this tag it would be good for users to use this tag to specifically tell this is installation related to SQL Server. It would ease the search as well.

Thanks

Comment: One can tag with both "sql-server" and "installation". Isn't this enough?

Comment: Well that is other way to do it thanks. But if one like to track installation questions just using one tag would 'SQL server installation' tag not help. If user has multiple technology experience he would like to minimise tags to keep track of questions.

Comment: (Re: your comment) I'm not sure what your argument is there. The technology in question is SQL Server and so the user would follow the `sql-server` tag. Or what did you mean?

Comment: Hi Andriy I just meant if it would be good to create a Tag for SQL Server installation. I agree to what Ypercude told Jack also gave some nice explanations. If questions which qualify just sql server why are there tags as Transaction log recovery backup shouldn't we have just a tag for each database, if I take what you said. And please consider this as discsuiion not argument. I am not here to argue

Answer (score 9):

This is absolutely the right place to ask the question - the downvotes here just indicate folk (including me) don't agree with the suggestion.

It would go completely against the grain of the way we tag which is basically:

1. Tag [for RDBMS](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/82/1396)
2. Tag for other stuff

There are only 155 questions [tagged installation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation) anyway - watching the whole tag and ignoring the other RDBMSs wouldn't be a bad option.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, well if you dont agree with suggesstion you should just say I dont. I dont think voting down a question would actualy say I dont agree its more like saying please think multiple times before posting any suggesstion. Anyways I can see you disagree in RDBMS post but did not downvoted the answer

Comment: People vote differently on meta, I'm just pointing that out. On main, downvotes mean "you shouldn't have asked that question here", on meta they just mean "I don't agree". I'm not saying that's good or bad, it is however a fact and knowing it can prevent misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4):

[wont-implement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wont-implement)

Sorry, but this is not how tagging works. We don't create an additional tag for each precipitously miniature use-case. We create large expansive tags that you apply as many as are reasonable (up to 5) to help people SEARCH for them in the future, like on le googles.

So, no. We won't do it. If we were to find out that people with sufficient privilege had ADDED it we would turn this into a tag-synonym for installation, so don't be clever.

Comment: Sorry to Jack for posting my answer after his, as I got sucked into a work conversation mid-reply (so basically hit submit after I finished the last sentence.

Comment: Are you saying that SQL Server installation is a precipitously miniature tag, well if so you are sadly mistaken. You got it all wrong when you thought it is for my personal use its for better way of qualifying the question not for my use you can always see at newest questions and will be updated to any new question which comes.

Comment: WRONG. You've got it all wrong.

Comment: It is a very narrow tag. There's a difference between [[ [tag:sql-server] | [tag:installation] ]] and [[ [tag:sql-server-installation] ]] ... they are definitely two different things.

Comment: I'm also telling you that I will synonymize it if I ever see it.

Comment: Is it a Narrow tag because StackExcahnge does not gets question related to SQL Server installation, did you ever guessed why ? May be users is not able to find answer here may be its voted down for whatever reason. We should encourage user to post I am Moderator on SQL Server forum and I deal with lots of SQL Server Installation question there. Though of giving as suggesstion here for tag but notheless its OK

Comment: I encourage people to post. I'm not against the idea of using MANY TAGS to find what you need. But honestly, the number of people using the tags page is very small. Most people are coming from google. Google doesn't care about if it's [sql server installation] or [sql server] [installation] as they will see the two the same for purposes of search results.

Comment: I have removed your comment because it does not contribute to the discussion. The message in question was removed as inappropriate and the message poster was given feedback directly on this matter. It was handled in chat, as it should have been.