# Editing a question to add a tag for RDBMS after the question has an answer

Tags: discussion

In the short time that I've been a member of the community I've noticed that the OP sometimes doesn't tag their question with the RDBMS (go figure :)).  Community members often ask for this information in the comments and/or the OP leaks the data via their question or comments.  I have edited a question to add a tag 5 to 10 times in the short time I've been a member.  At the same time there are community members with more rep/seniority who surely noticed the missing tag and had the information to apply the proper tag before I did.

I'm not trying to say that everyone should add RDBMS tags to questions.  I understand several factors can be in play such as; time constraints, effort/reward/community benefit judgments, a feeling that it is not their place, low perceived value based on the substance of the question, I don't have the rep to see they already did edit to add the tag, etc.

My question is there a **purposeful** reason why they are not editing the question to add the tag?  Or worded differently; is there a reason why adding a tag is detrimental?  I only see benefits from the tag which makes me wonder if I'm missing something, because most things are a give and take.

Comment: I'm not trying to suggest that these tags **should** be required as suggested [in this](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/why-is-rdbms-type-not-a-required-field-on-this-exchange) meta question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Is there a purposeful reason why they are not editing the question to add the tag?*

Maybe some people are hesitant about bumping questions to the front page, or perhaps they just don't want their name on the question in the *'modified by x minutes ago'* position.

I frequently notice  people (not just you!) editing in the database product tag when it is provided in a comment or elsewhere, often when it was quite a distance from the question itself. This is a *very good thing*.

Perhaps the number of such tasks exceeds the available person-power sometimes? Perhaps you're especially skilled at finding product tag candidates? Anyway, keep up the great work.

> *Is there a reason why adding a tag is detrimental?*

I cannot think of any drawbacks to adding the proper product tag(s) to a question. Tags help people and search engines find questions (and answers).

We could sometimes be better at adding top-level tags (e.g. [sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)) whenever we add a version tag (e.g. [sql-server-2014](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014)), but that is a [separate topic.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/82/1192)

Comment: Ok good.  I was just worried I was missing something.  I wasn't thinking people were slacking or I was the only one doing this work.  I certainly understand that there are **lots** of reasons why the tag might be missing.  :)

Comment: @Erik Well, it's always possible I'm missing something too :) By the way, there is no subtext or implied criticism to any part of my answer - I think we're doing a pretty decent job in this area, and your efforts are genuinely appreciated.

Comment: I didn't think you were criticizing me. I just wanted to make it abundantly clear that I'm not criticizing others.  In some circles posing this kind of question could be perceived negatively/accusatory and text can be misinterpreted.

Comment: @Erik "in some circles...": true, but [not here](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/1311/1396) ;)

Comment: @Erik keep up the good work. We mods agree this is good site hygiene.